# How to scan a file line by line in an anonymous function and pass it down a channel

Tags: go, anonymous-function

I want to write a function that reads lines from a file and sends then into a channel for further processing. I'm new to Go and here is the reader function I came up with following mostly textbook examples:

```
func reader(file string) <-chan string {
    out := make(chan string)

    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    s := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    go func() {
        for s.Scan() {
            out <- s.Text()
        }
        close(out)
    }()

    return out
}
```

In the `main()` function I pass a file pointer into the reader function and try to drain the out channel as follows:

```
func main() {
    out := reader(*f)
    for range out {
        fmt.Println(<-out)
    }
}
```

I get no comilation or runtime errors, however, the output is empty. If I don't put the for loop into a goroutine I can print the file from withing the `reader()` function w/o any problems.

I've furthermore tried to pass the Scanner, channel or both in the `reader()` function into the anonymous function. But it didn't solve the problem. Can anyone explain please why this code does not work and how to remedy it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing the file before you read it.

You're only printing every other line.

Move the defer into the closure where the reads actually happen.

```
func reader(file string) <-chan string {
    out := make(chan string)

    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    s := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    go func() {
        defer f.Close()
        defer close(out)
        for s.Scan() {
            out <- s.Text()
        }
        if err := s.Err(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error reading file:", err)
        }
    }()

    return out
}
```

Then print the value from the range clause, not a second value received within the for loop:

```
func main() {
    out := reader(os.Args[1])
    for line := range out {
        fmt.Println(line)
    }
}
```